# DB2 803 Unique constraint error

Tags: db2, unique-constraint

I am hitting a request which enters a record into a table. Now this request enters the record in table but also throws sql 803 (unique constraint error) although there is no duplicate record and the created date shows the current date only.
Please let me know how its possible to insert a record and simultaneously throwing unique constraint error.

Answer (score 0):

It's not.

You are mis-understanding something about what's going on.

One possibility, there's a trigger on the target of your insert that is inserting into or updating another table.  It's the second insert/update throwing the constraint error.

Normally, triggers operate under the same transaction as the original operation; so that if an error occurs the original operation is rolled back.  Depending on your version and platform, it's possible the trigger was set up (incorrectly?) to operate outside the firing transaction.  Possibly more likely, your insert is being done outside a transaction so the 2nd  insert/update is also.  When it fails, the original is not rolled back.

Comment: As checked with the query SELECT *
FROM SYSCAT.TRIGGERS there are no triggers on my table..